# How to find and replace all 'null' date occurences in MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, replace, null

Also replacing other formats later, such as: finding all dates with 'dd/mm/YYYY' format and changing them to ISO 'YYYY-mm-dd' format.

But as for the 'null' issue, this is the *.js* I am trying to run in MongoDB (NoSQLBooster):

```
use sms
           
db.collection1.find({
    "FirstDate":null
})
    .projection({})
    //.sort({ _id: -1 })
    //.limit(1000)
    .forEach(function(doc) {
        var date = doc.FirstDate
        if (date == null) {
            date = ''
        }
    })
```

And all I'm getting is "undefined" results. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` with `{multi: true}` to ensure all values that match are updated (not only the first one)

```
db.collection.update({
  FirstDate: null
},
{
  $set: {
    FirstDate: ""
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/emca81O_FI5)

Comment: That worked just fine! The mongo playground also presents itself as a great test and learning tool. Now I'm trying to save all _id keys for a simple 'find' query, but it seems the free version does not have any means of copying/exporting. Guess I'll have to do it blindly